# Ignore first few lines and last few lines in a file Linux

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file like this and would like to print `$0` except the first two and last three lines in linux. Tried `awk` command but no luck, is there any options I am using the following command - I suppose I am doing something wrong, but not able to figure out what it is with my minimal experience in computer science.

```
  awk '{if(NR>2){c++}else if(FNR<=c-3){print $0}}' samplefile.out > sampleout.txt

entry0 45
entry0 42
entry1 41
entry2 78
entry3 89
entry4 68
entryn 58
entryn 33
etnryn 52
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

awk cannot look ahead so you'll have to save the lines.

```
awk 'NR>2{if(z!="")print z;z=y;y=x;x=$0}' file
```

Practically zero memory overhead

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a combination of `head` and `tail`:

```
tail -n +2 samplefile.out | head -n -3 > sampleout.txt
```

Comment: I think this should probably have been the accepted answer as it is the ideal way to do this, especially as my way would become unmaintainable with more lines.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
awk 'NR>2{a[++j]=$0}END{for (i=1;i<=j-3;i++){print a[i]}}' samplefile.out
```

There's no way to calculate the lines of the file if you don't read or save previous line first.

If the archive is too big , `head` + `tail` mix could be better to avoid a memory overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this, but it uses `array`

```
$ cat file
entry0 45
entry0 42
entry1 41
entry2 78
entry3 89
entry4 68
entryn 58
entryn 33
etnryn 52

$ awk 'NR>first+last{print A[NR%last]}{A[NR%last]=$0}' first=2 last=3 file
entry1 41
entry2 78
entry3 89
entry4 68
```